# Generate viable sampling distributions of discrete data in R

Tags: r, correlation, data-generation

I'm trying to simulate 2 X 2 data that would yield a relatively strong negative phi coefficients.

I'm using the library `GenOrd` as follows:

```
library(GenOrd)

# Specify sample size N
N <- 40

# Marginal distribution
marginal <- list(c(.5), c(.5))

# Matrix
Sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, -.71, -.71, 1.0), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)

# Generate a sample of the categorical variables with specified parameters
m <- ordsample(N, marginal, Sigma)
```

However, I'm getting the following error whenever I input a correlation larger than `-.70`.

```
Error in contord(list(marginal[[q]], marginal[[r]]), matrix(c(1, Sigma[q,  : 
Correlation matrix not valid!
```

I'm clearly specifying something untenable somewhere - but I don't know what it is.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a go at answering this as a coding question. The error points to where the packages spots the problem beginning: at your Sigma entry. Given your marginal distribution, having -.71 in your corr. matrix is out of bounds and the packages is warning you of this. You can see this by altering the signs in your Sigma:

```
Sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, .71, .71, 1.0), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
m <- ordsample(N, marginal, Sigma)
> m
       [,1] [,2]
  [1,]    1    1
  [2,]    1    2
  ....
```

As to WHY -.71 is not valid, you may want to direct that statistical question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for a succinct answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted this to cross-validated. Yes, everything between `-.70` and `+1.00` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure "why", however, I found no problems simulating 2 X 2 data that would yield a relatively strong negative correlation using the `generate.binary()` function from the `MultiOrd` package.

For example, the following code will work for the complete range of correlation inputs. The documentation for the `generate.binary()` function indicates that the matrix specified is interpreted as a tetrachoric correlation matrix.

```
library(MultiOrd)

# Specify sample size N
N <- 40

# Marginal distribution for two variables as a vector for MultiOrd rather than a list
marginal <- c(.5, .5)

# Correlation (tetrachoric) matrix as target for simulated relationship between variables
Sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, -.71, -.71, 1.0), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)

# Generate a sample of the categorical variables with specified parameters
m <- generate.binary(40, marginal, Sigma)
```